# I am trying to implement google autocomplete search, but facing issue - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'predictionsNew' of undefined?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, auto-populate

Please tell me how to store those predictions in one more array so that i can use that to populate in view.  i don't know where iam doing wrong, iam new to coding, please help me fixing this.

```
                 <input type="text" placeholder="Pick one" (input)="initService($event)" aria-label="Number" matInput
                    [formControl]="myControl" formControlName="source" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
                  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of predictionsNew" 
                    [value]="option.description" (onSelect)="stopselect($event, 's');">
                      {{option.description}}
                    </mat-option>
                  </mat-autocomplete>


initService(event) {
    this.predictionsNew;
    if (event.target.value.length > 3) {

      const displaySuggestions = function (
        predictions: google.maps.places.QueryAutocompletePrediction[],
        status: google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus
      ) {
        if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
          alert(status);
          return;
        }
        this.predictionsNew = (predictions); //here iam getting error - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'predictionsNew' of undefined?
 
      };

      const service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
      service.getQueryPredictions({ input: event.target.value }, displaySuggestions);
    }
  }
```

Comment: I think it's because displaySuggestions is a function so "this" inside it is not what you think it is. try service.getQueryPredictions({ input: event.target.value }, displaySuggestions.bind(this));

Comment: It worked thank you @ihorbond

Answer (score 0):

You have to define predictionsNew as a global empty array initially.

```
predictionsNew = [];
```

Also on initService function, replace this.predictionsNew; with this.predictionsNew = [];

Comment: replace this.predictionsNew; with this.predictionsNew = []; in initService